# Can we download OSM map tiles and use it for commercial product

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I am working on commercial product, where I have to use map tiles in the offline.
I have downloaded tiles from OSM

[https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png).

Can we use these tiles for commercial product by downloading the tiles and placing in my server(I might have to edit the tile images in terms of colors).

**Update**

In the same way Can we download the tiles from the domain ?
https://openstreetmap.in/#5/22.150/79.081

If this is also same policy why private key/token is is mentioned here?
https://github.com/osm-in/openstreetmap.in#using-this-map

Comment: If you have a specific question about usage of a product, best you ask the people who own it rather than a bunch of people on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, but...

Using OSM tiles for commercial purposes is allowed as already mentioned in [Gilles-Antoine Nys's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52478808/1340631) as long as you add proper attribution. See the [Licence and Legal FAQ](https://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Licence/Licence_and_Legal_FAQ) as well as the [OSM tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/) for details.

However you are not allowed to bulk download OSM tiles! OSM tile servers have limited resources and this will result in getting banned. If you need lots of tiles then either [render your own tiles](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) or get into contact with a [third-party tile provider](https://switch2osm.org/providers/).

Answer (score 1):

OSM maps are distributed under License : Open Data Commons Open Database License.

> You are free to copy, distribute, transmit and adapt our data, as long
>   as you credit OpenStreetMap and its contributors. If you alter or
>   build upon our data, you may distribute the result only under the same
>   licence. The full legal code explains your rights and
>   responsibilities.
>
> The cartography in our map tiles, and our documentation, are licensed
>   under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 2.0 license (CC
>   BY-SA).

So the answer is **Yes**, but with restrictions.

Accordingly to [Copyright and License - OSM Webpage](https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)

Comment: So I can download some tiles and place it my server(With alteration)  ofcourse we will give credit to OSM.
And I found two domains which are .ORG and .in  what they are could you please explain it

Comment: At least all apis of the genre are working with keys.

Comment: .in is for India. It has different borders and a different map style.